# Set the beginning of a curly brace to a new line in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, curly-braces

I am writing/debugging Javascript code in Visual Studio 2015 and hate to have the curly braces of a function starting at the end of an expression (btw: why is it like this as it is way less clearly arranged?) like:

```
$scope.adjusted = function () {
    console.log(adjustedYesNo);
}
```

Instead I want to have it started by default (and after each change) in the beginning of a line like:

```
$scope.adjusted = function () 
{
    console.log(adjustedYesNo);
}
```

Where to set such a setting in Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the menu go to...

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript > Formatting > New Lines
```

Set the options as required in there.  You can do this individually for each of the supported languages.

Comment: And this will not add a new line for `} else`.

Comment: @AnastasiosMoraitis This doesn't actually do anything, other than point you at the location of formatting options for JavaScript.  You have to choose what you want.

Comment: Yes, I mean that there is no option to format an else statement. I fixed it by using ReSharper.

Answer (score 5):

***Go to:***

> Options -> Text Editor -> Javascript -> Formatting - > New Lines ->
>   Braces

- and there are two checkmarks about braces on new line